# Is a kiddushin valid if one just gives a ring but doesn't say "harei at mekudeshes li?"

Tags: halacha, marriage, kiddushin-eirusin, maseches-kiddushin

If someone were to just give a ring and not say anything (everything else is Kosher- witnesses etc) would this be considered a valid *kiddushin* or do we require the saying of "*harei at*" to make it valid?

Comment: Were this true wouldn't I be married to all sorts of women that I've given things to in public before?

Comment: See Kidusshin 6a-b, starting here-ish: https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.6a.8?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Are you talking about the case where there is intent (on his and her part) for the ring to effect _kiddushin_ or is this just a case of a man giving a woman a ring?

Comment: @Salmononius2 thanks! I know that *gemara*, and seems to say that it would be a valid kiddushin, but probably not smart to do it *lchatchilah*. Curious how we *pasken* l'maaseh tho

Comment: @Daniel the former, and nothing is said. Seems to be that as long as both of them knew the intent than it would be a valid kiddushin right?

Comment: @DoubleAA haha- probably haven't given all those gifts in front of eidim/ chuppah etc tho

Comment: @alicht all the time in front of eidim. There are eidim outside all over the place. Ha.

Comment: @Double was it shalach manos??:)

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a legitimate question with a clear answer in Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @MDjava so is "can I steal your car?"

Comment: Chukim are obvious. Ishut is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is at the time of wedding, under the chupa, it's good.

Mishna in maaser sheni 4.7

> היה מדבר עמה על עסקי גיטה וקדושיה ונתן לה גיטה וקדושיה ולא פרש 
>   רבי יוסי אומר דיו, רבי יהודה אומר צריך לפרש
>
> Bartenura שעסוקים באותו ענין ומתוך אותם הדברים עמד וגירש או קידש אין צריך לפרש, והלכה כרבי יוסי.‏

Gemara kiddushin 6a

> אמר רב יהודה אמר שמואל והוא שעסוקים באותו ענין ... מענין לענין באותו ענין

SA EH 27.1

> ...
>   וְאִם הָיָה מְדַבֵּר עִמָּהּ תְּחִלָּה עַל עִסְקֵי קִדּוּשִׁין, וְנָתַן לָהּ אֲפִלּוּ בִּשְׁתִיקָה, הָוֵי קִדּוּשִׁין. וְהוּא שֶׁעֲדַיִן עֲסוּקִין בְּאוֹתוֹ עִנְיָן. וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן אִם אָמַר לְשׁוֹן קִדּוּשִׁין וַדַּאי, אֶלָּא שֶׁאֵינָהּ מְבִינָה אוֹתוֹ, דַּהֲווּ קִדּוּשִׁין. הגה: יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּלָא בָּעִינָן מְדַבְּרִים בְּאוֹתוֹ עִנְיָן מַמָּשׁ, אֶלָּא מְדַבְּרִים מֵעִנְיָן לְעִנְיָן בְּאוֹתוֹ עִנְיָן, דְּהַיְנוּ שֶׁאֵין מְדַבְּרִים בְּקִדּוּשִׁין, רַק בְּצָרְכֵי זִוּוּגָם (מָרְדְּכַי סוֹף הָאִישׁ מְקַדֵּשׁ וְכ''כ הָרַשְׁבָּ''א). וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּלֹא בָּעִינָן מְדַבְּרִים עִמָּהּ, אֶלָּא כָּל שֶׁמְּדַבְּרִים לְפָנֶיהָ, סָגֵי (מָרְדְּכַי רֵישׁ קִדּוּשִׁין, וְכֵן מַשְׁמָע לְשׁוֹן הַטּוּר):‏

If he (the chatan) was talking to her about her kiddushin... HAGA:  There are opinions we don't need properly speaking a speech about Kiddushin, e.g. speaking about zivug, (Rashba, Mordechai). Following some opinions, even if other people are speaking in front of them (in Mordechai and Tur).

The details aren't obvious, but there is anyway possible to make kiddushin without saying hare at. Baer heytev reports some stringencies in name of Mahari Ben Lev, cases wherein despite some contextual conditions evocative of kiddushin, the kiddushin are safek.

Comment: Cf. Kiddushin 6a, Rambam Ishus 3:8, Even HaEzer 27:1